# How to use continue or break with For ... in with Javascript Illegal continue statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I am looping through my property as following :

```
for (let propertyName in dataObject) {
   if (propertyName=='name'){
       if (dataObject[propertyName] == 'Coco'){
         continue;
         }
    }
      myFunctionTransfer(dataObject[propertyName]);
}
```

I am getting the error

> Illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statementIllegal
>   continue statement: no surrounding iteration statement

How can I achieve what I want to achieve ? when the name property value is 'Coco' the for loop should go to the next property.

Comment: `continue` => `break` ?

Comment: Why not just do the opposite logic. Meaning, when the name is not Coco, do whatever you want. ```if (dataObject[propertyName] != 'Coco'){
         //do your logic;}```

Comment: beside the nested `if` clause, which could be replaced with a single one and `&&`, the code is working. maybe you have in `myFunctionTransfer` a `continue` statement.

Comment: Are you sure this is where the error is thrown? That code is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the for loop as follows:

```
for (let propertyName in dataObject) {
   if (propertyName != 'name' || dataObject[propertyName] != 'Coco') {
      myFunctionTransfer(dataObject[propertyName]);
    }      
}
```

Comment: What's wrong in my answer? I've simply changed the code in order to match the condition which the `for` body should be applyied for...

Comment: Great, this hack worked for me